# How to extract a multiple quoted substrings in Java

Tags: java, regex, string, substring

I have a string that has multiple substring which has to be extracted. Strings which will be extracted is between `'` character.

I could only extract the first or the last one when I use indexOf or regex.

How could I extract them and put them into array or list without parsing the same string only?

```
resultData = "Error 205: 'x' data is not crawled yet. Check 'y' and 'z' data and update dataset 't'";
```

I have a tried below;

```
protected static String errorsTPrinted(String errStr, int errCode) { 

if (errCode== 202 ) {

ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'(.*?)'");
Matcher m = p.matcher(errStr);
String text;

for (int i = 0; i < errStr.length(); i++) {

m.find();
text = m.group(1);
ar.add(text);
}

return errStr = "Err 202: " + ar.get(0) + " ... " + ar.get(1) + " ..." + ar.get(2) + " ... " + ar.get(3);
}
```

**Edit**

I used @MinecraftShamrock 's approach.

```
if (errCode== 202 ) {
List<String> getQuotet = getQuotet(errStr, '\'');
return errStr = "Err 202: " + getQuotet.get(0) + " ... " + getQuotet.get(1) + " ..." + getQuotet.get(2) + " ... " + getQuotet.get(3);
}
```

Comment: This shouldn't be that complex. Can you post something you already tried and got frustated enough to end up running here?

Comment: `'(.*?)'` is what you want. I won't show you full solution, first try by yourself and let us know if you have problems.

Comment: @MarounMaroun I have tried it, I only get 'x' as a result and y,z,t results disappears.

Comment: You should loop on all matches.

Comment: @LunaticFnatic add that to your _question_. That is exactly _why_ this is an "edit" button.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sorry, you're right. I've added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this very straightforward algorithm to do so and avoid regex (as one can't be 100% sure about its complexity):

```
public List<String> getQuotet(final String input, final char quote) {
    final ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    int n = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if(input.charAt(i) == quote) {
            if(n == -1) { //not currently inside quote -> start new quote
                n = i + 1;
            } else { //close current quote
                result.add(input.substring(n, i));
                n = -1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

This works with any desired quote-character and has a runtime complexity of O(n). If the string ends with an open quote, it will not be included. However, this can be added quite easily.

I think this is preferable over regex as you can ba absolutely sure about its complexity. Also, it works with a minimum of library classes. If you care about efficiency for big inputs, use this.

And last but not least, it does absolutely not care about what is between two quote characters so it works with any input string.

Comment: This is a very nice approach. I am parsing a json error code and simply change its language. Not quite familiar with parsing variables in json text so I am parsing its substrings and re-write the error. I better use it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the pattern:

```
'([^']++)'
```

And a `Matcher` like so:

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("'([^']++)'");
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(resultData);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

This loops through each match in the `String` and prints it.

Output:

```
x
y
z
t
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple approach (assuming there are no escaping characters etc.):

```
// Compile a pattern to find the wanted strings
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'([^']+)'");
// Create a matcher for given input
Matcher m = p.matcher(resultData);
// A list to put the found strings into
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
// Loop over all occurrences
while(m.find()) {
  // Retrieve the matched text
  String text = m.group(1);
  // Do something with the text, e.g. add it to a List
  list.add(text);
}
```